# Android - Create an in-app retractable message bar

Tags: android, user-interface, in-app

I am trying to create what I call an "application status bar" (probably not the correct term) that will display application state indications for the user ("connecting...", "loading...", etc.).

I have made several attempts on my own but I am not really a UI/UX programmer and everything I tried, including tween animations, just seems plain ugly :-)

Is there a library or a best practice to do something like that? I failed to find anything on Google.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: do you want it to be a persistent one or someting popping out now and then when the status changes?. For the latter you can use `SnackBar`

Comment: @PrerakSola You're right. Usually I try to do it right but I guess I got lazy this time. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nom1fan, you can use the snackbar widget from the Google support design library.  Here's an example use of it:

```
Snackbar.make(getView(), "connecting...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

where getView() returns a view in your currently displayed layout

Comment: I didn't find that when searching, it sounds like what I'm looking for. Going to check it out now and if it's what I need I'll mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: This is what I wanted but unfortunately I had to use a 3rd party snackbar. Trying to use Google Support design library was a nightmare for me. after updateding to API 23 (downloaded all needed packages from SDK manager), I tried using the snackbar and it seems it cannot work inside Activity? only ActivityCompat? I tried that too which made my whole UI very ugly and still did not work! Did anyone else experience such difficulties?

Comment: Hi Nom1fan, I am not sure what is wrong with your use of AppCompatActivity.  It is pretty standard to use AppCompatActivity instead of Activity.  I suggest you get familiar with AppCompatActivity.

Comment: For some reason when I changed to inherit from it, my UI (buttons, image buttons, and action bar) completely changed and looked much worse. Maybe I Need to familiar myself with the styles then. I will definitely give it another shot because of what you said. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, being familiar with styles will definitely help you.  You're on the right path, so keep up with the hard work :)